# Can I know who voted up/down my question/answer?

Tags: discussion, votes

I want to know that can I know that who voted up/down my question/answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Who votes for whom is held in strict confidence by SE. There is no way to find out who voted for your questions or answers, and who you vote for will not be revealed.

Comment: As moderator, even I am not privy to this information.